# Help creating servlet in existing jsf project

Tags: java, jsf, servlets

I'm trying to create a servlet inside a JSF project. This is the first servlet that I've created and I'm using http://www.servletworld.com/servlet-tutorials/simple-servlet-example.html as an example to get me started.

The only thing is my folder structure is a little different because of the existing jsf.

I can get the form.html page to display, but when I type my name in and click submit, I get a 404.

My folder structure is as follows (only relevant files shown)

---

```
catalog (my project in eclipse)
- src
  - a
    - b
      - c
        - catalog
          - backing
            - WelcomeServlet.java
- WebContent
  - catalog
    - form.html
  - WEB-INF
    - web.xml
    - classes
      - a
        - b
          - c
            - catalog
              - backing
                - WelcomeServlet.class
```

Here is the servlet mappings in web.xml

```
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>WelcomeServlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>a.b.c.catalog.backing.WelcomeServlet</servlet-class>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>WelcomeServlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/WelcomeServlet</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
<welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>/form.html </welcome-file>
</welcome-file-list>

<servlet>
    <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet</servlet-class>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>

<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>*.jsf</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>

<welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>/index.jsp</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>/index.html</welcome-file>
</welcome-file-list>
```

This url brings up the form.html page just fine http://localhost:8080/catalog/catalog/form.html

When you click the submit button, it brings up the url http://localhost:8080/catalog/catalog/WelcomeServlet and it gives a 404 error. I'm thinking that there is an issue in my web.xml file, but i'm not certain and I can't figure this out.

Thanks

Comment: Do you have any other servlet-mappings declared in web.xml?

Comment: yes. I've edited the question with the rest of the servlet-mappings for the jsf piece.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try adding this after the first servlet mapping:

```
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>WelcomeServlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/catalog/WelcomeServlet</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

Comment: This works, but I would consider it a workaround.  I can't imagine the url _catalog/catalog/WelcomeServlet_ would be the intention of the developer.

Comment: There are some path questions to be cleared up: the context root could probably be cleaner but I expect that particular artifact is based on how the JSP page is generating the links. If the JSP doesn't double up on the context root then the extra catalog wouldn't have to be there.

Answer (score 0):

From what I see, your servlet is mapped to *contextroot*/WelcomeServlet, and you're navigating to *contextroot*/catalog/WelcomeServlet.  They're not the same thing.

I'm guessing you forgot a slash in your html.

Comment: Sorry, but i'm not following what needs to be done. Can you please elaborate?